# IFrame Embedding of a dynamic RoR page doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iframe

this one's a head-scratcher.

We have a RoR page set up which dynamically pulls data from the URL and loads up the appropriate video. For example: http://rayku.com/video?name=Alg2_07_02_0015

However, whenever we try to iframe embed this, nothing gets loaded:

```
<iframe src="http://rayku.com/video?name=Alg2_07_02_0015" width="674" height="379"></iframe>
```

The PHP equivalent for embedding works fine when put into an iframe: http://ouyang.ca/video.php?name=Alg2_07_02_0015

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails sets the [x-frame-options header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) to disallow this by default, so browsers that respect this header won't allow iframing

You can change this either everywhere:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers['X-Frame-Options'] = ...
```

Or if you need something a bit more fine grained, then you can set that header as you would any other header

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! I just changed the setting in application_controller and that did the trick.